# No low rep voting, please!

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

There is a system-wide plan to test lower voting threshholds - basically 1 point for up or down voting (so any new registered user) with no downvote penalty. [The full details are here on Meta SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on?cb=1).

The powers that be are asking for sites to volunteer. I just want to state for the record here that I am very much against this idea. The numbers can (and maybe should) be tweaked a bit, but allowing totally new users to vote without any other interaction is, in my opinion, a disaster waiting to happen. I encourage others to upvote this and/or to write an answer with more coherent arguments, so that it can be clear where this site stands on this policy.

And if this is the wrong way to do this, let me know. But since they are looking for sites to volunteer for testing, I think it is important to discuss.

Comment: It usually takes time for a new person to learn the ins and outs of a new to them site.  Maybe a non counting "like/non like" button would be okay for new users and be for them only to learn.

Comment: I see more than enough up votes (I presume from reviews which prompt to "vote accordingly" if you review a first question and say it's OK) on low quality questions that I'd have to agree that adding in new-user voting probably would be a `Bad Thing™`.

Comment: [Once I reach 15 reputation, will my old votes be taken into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account). "thank you for your feedback but..." - No. It's all lies. - It already is 'non counting' which is a huge turn off when I go spout some crap at some other site **that I don't belong on**... so it's by design working as intended. The only thing that's changed is SO's mission statement now being the reverse of quality over quantity.